# ImageServer / GDAL Error

Tags: qgis, gdal, curl

I am attempting to add an ImageServer layer to my project (QGIS 3.4.2 22034aa070 on Windows 1803) using the following command:

```
qgis.utils.iface.addRasterLayer("https://gis.maine.gov/arcgis/rest/services/Elevation/Maine_Elevation_DEM_2_Meter_Image_Service/ImageServer", "Maine DEM")
```

I receive the following error:

```
Invalid Layer: GDAL provider Cannot open GDAL dataset https://gis.maine.gov/arcgis/rest/services/Elevation/Maine_Elevation_DEM_2_Meter_Image_Service/ImageServer: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate Raster layer Provider is not valid (provider: gdal, URI: https://gis.maine.gov/arcgis/rest/services/Elevation/Maine_Elevation_DEM_2_Meter_Image_Service/ImageServer
```

[Based on this thread it seems to be a known issue only evident on Windows that was supposedly resolved 19 months ago.](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/gdal-dev-libcurl-and-the-certificates-and-Windows-td5322919.html)

I receive a similar error when running QGIS 2.18 on Ubuntu 18.04

```
Invalid Layer: GDAL provider Cannot open GDAL dataset https://gis.maine.gov/arcgis/rest/services/Elevation/Maine_Elevation_DEM_2_Meter_Image_Service/ImageServer: An error occurred while creating a virtual connection to the DAP server: Error while reading the URL: https://gis.maine.gov/arcgis/rest/services/Elevation/Maine_Elevation_DEM_2_Meter_Image_Service/ImageServer.ver. The OPeNDAP server returned the following message: Bad Request: Raster layer Provider is not valid (provider: gdal, URI: https://gis.maine.gov/arcgis/rest/services/Elevation/Maine_Elevation_DEM_2_Meter_Image_Service/ImageServer
```

Could anyone provide assistance with adding the Maine.gov ImageServers to QGIS projects?

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell gdal to ignore SSL certificate errors by running the following in the Python Console from within QGIS (from Plugins>>Python Console):

```
import gdal
gdal.SetConfigOption('GDAL_HTTP_UNSAFESSL', 'YES')
```

Unfortunately it looks like you're trying to use an ImageServer, which QGIS isn't really natively compatible with right now and I haven't had success with the ImageServer plugin. I anticipate the next error you'll get will be

> Invalid Layer: GDAL provider Cannot open GDAL dataset /vsicurl/ ... /ImageServer' not recognized as a supported file format. Raster layer Provider is not valid

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the code for use in future situations, but this ImageServer continues to produce the same error message.